# Azure function not triggering every 2 minutes as expected

Tags: function, azure

I have a function that is configured to trigger every 2 minutes (`[TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]`) but when checking the monitor we see it being triggered randomly at different intervals:

`2018-12-11 17:42:00.003
2018-12-11 17:40:00.017
2018-12-11 17:24:00.022
2018-12-11 17:12:00.018
2018-12-11 17:06:00.006
2018-12-11 16:58:00.013
2018-12-11 16:34:42.473
2018-12-11 16:34:00.008`

The average duration for each iteration is 45 seconds.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I would recommend to remove function and to recreate it (redeploy).

Comment: Can you check your streaming logs?  What are they showing?

Comment: Deleted the function on Azure and redeployed it. The first 4 instances were triggered properly, after that it started getting random again.

Comment: @DAlvarenga Could you go to kudu `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` for detailed logs. The monitor panel may not capture all logs.